# Upstart not triggering sysinit

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

Upon server boot Upstart runs but does not trigger the transition to the normal runlevel, and I would like to know how to fix it. For example syslog will have been started, time set and so on, but Apache, Cyrus IMAP, Postfix and other services are not started.

If I execute `telinit 2` all the remaining init scripts are run as normal. The server is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which was just upgraded from 10.04 LTS and was 8.04 LTS a while before that. I cannot confirm that this is a consequence of the upgrade as I had noticed problems with services on reboot before, past month or two, but didn't pin it on Upstart. I'm pretty good with the rest of the system but don't know much about Upstart, so I'm not sure what to include for extra information but I'll provide anything necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have either hard-coded a different runlevel in your kernel command line via grub (`cat /proc/cmdline`), or maybe you have a custom local `/etc/inittab`? Also, what does the output of `/sbin/runlevel` show when you first login?